# why is converting strings to ints in my lambda function slower than converting with list comprehension

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

I have used the following two methods ina Codeeval problem,I used the first method originally and thought I could speed it up by removing converting strings to ints from the lists to the lambda but it actually slowed the code down considerably, why is this so?

```
with open("multiply.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line1 = line[:line.find("|")].split()
        line2 = line[line.find("|")+1:].split()
        line1_int = [int(x) for x in line1 ]
        line2_int = [int(x) for x in line2]
        mult= map(lambda x, y: x*y, line1_int, line2_int)
        print " ".join(str(s) for s in mult)

 with open("multiply.txt") as f:   
    for line in f:
        line1 = line[:line.find("|")].split()
        line2 = line[line.find("|")+1:].split()
        mult= map(lambda x, y: int(x)* int(y), line1, line2)
        print " ".join(str(s) for s in mult)
```

Comment: how bout `mult = [int(x)*int(y) for x,y in zip(line1,line2)]` ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce - the second version is consistently faster (by not much). Please include a way to generate an input file on which you are seeing the behaviour, and provide the details of your Python version and platform. And please also include your timings.

Comment: @JoranBeasley you don't even need `zip`, `(line1,line2)` is just `map(str.split,line.split("|"))`

Comment: Also note that your lambda is unnecessary in the first place -- just use `map(operator.mul, line1, line2)`.

Comment: I am using python2.7.3, I ran the code multiple times on the codeEval grader, the second function scored lower each time and was much slower  in comparison to the first function, the first averaged about 170ms the second 130ms, the input file was 40 lines long which consisted of two lists seperated by a "|".

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham The *second* solution is faster if it takes 40 fewer milliseconds to run than the first. That's the opposite of your question.

Comment: @MaxNoel, not on codeEval, maybe it has something to do with the input file but I tried repeatedly against the input file and it was always as my question suggests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the list comprehension, `int` is looked up one time, and the code object it is bound to can be used for each element of the list. The lambda expression creates a function object in which `int` needs to be looked up each time it is *called*, since as a non-local name it may have been rebound between calls.

Something like

```
lambda x, y, i=int: i(x) * i(y), line1, line2
```

should be faster, as `i` is now a local variable lookup when the function is called, not a global lookup as `int` required.

Update: some quick timing tests in Python 2.7:

```
# Using lists of integers
% python -m timeit -n 100 -s 'list1=range(10); list2=range(10)' \
  'map(lambda x,y: x*y, list1, list2)'
100 loops, best of 3: 2.13 usec per loop
# Convert str to int at multiplication time
% python -m timeit -n 100 -s 'list1=map(str,range(10)); list2=map(str,range(10))' \
   'map(lambda x,y: int(x)*int(y), list1, list2)'
100 loops, best of 3: 19 usec per loop
# Convert str to int, using localized int function
% python -m timeit -n 100 -s 'list1=map(str,range(10)); list2=map(str,range(10))' \
  'map(lambda x,y,i=int: i(x)*i(y), list1, list2)'
100 loops, best of 3: 14.2 usec per loop
```

Note that my first test doesn't require converting a list of strings to integers as part of  the test, to isolate the effect of name lookups in the call to `map`. Needing to do so would slow the first test down. For comparison, here's a test which does take the time to convert a list of strings to a list of ints prior to the call to `map`:

```
% python -m timeit -n 100 -s 'list1=map(str,range(10)); list2=map(str,range(10))' \
  'list1=[int(x) for x in list1]; list2=[int(x) for x in list2]; map(lambda x,y: int(x)*int(y), list1, list2)'
100 loops, best of 3: 9.77 usec per loop
```

Slower, but still faster than calling `int` inside the `lambda`.

Comment: well the code runs slower, for me anyway doing the string to int in the lambda so it must be the reason why

Answer (score 1):

[@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) answered your question beautifully! I'll take a bit of time for some code review, then.

```
with open('multiply.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line1,line2 = map(str.split,line.split("|"))
        mult = [x*y for x,y in zip(map(int,line1),map(int,line2))]
        print(' '.join(str(s) for s in mult))
```

Comment: that gives the error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''"
" as there are spaces separating the chars in the input file.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham whoops, sorry I re-typed my code rather than copy/paste, so I missed a `map`

Comment: thanks the "line1,line2 = map(str.split,line.split("|"))" will be very useful for the next challenges.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham keep in mind it only works because we're splitting on whitespace, so I can call the function and assume default arguments. If I had to split on `.` or something, I'd have to write a lambda (`map(lambda x: x.split('.'), split("|")`)

Comment: can I pass multiple arguments to split someway or would I have to use something like re.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham [let's talk about it in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47903/why-is-converting-strings-to-ints-in-my-lambda-function-slower-than-converting-wi)